# Can a Queue be rescheduled in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, queue, octobercms

**Task:**

I am creating a way that a frontend user can send a message and schedule a time for it to be delivered.  To accomplish this, I am storing the message info in database tables and then Setting a queue to fire a send function at the appropriate time.

**Question:**

If the user changes their mind about the time to send the message after this code is executed, is there a way to remove this from the queue and then re add it to fire at a different time?

**Example**

```
$data = ['message_id' => $this->messageModel->id];
$queue = Queue::later($this->send_at, 'KurtJensen\Twilio\Classes\SendQueue', $data);

// ==== Everything works great up to this point =======

// Don't know if this will work
// Can I get a queue identifier here?

$this->messageModel->queue_id = $queue->id;
$this->messageModel->save();
```

Then later to change time:

```
$this->messageModel= Message::find($id);
$q_id = $this->messageModel->queue_id;

// ==== I doubt this would work or if canceling a queue is possible ======= 
Queue::cancel($q_id);

$queue = Queue::later($new_time, 'KurtJensen\Twilio\Classes\SendQueue', $data);

$this->messageModel->queue_id = $queue->id;
$this->messageModel->save();
```

Comment: Couldn't you run a queue every [1,5,10,15]minutes and have it cycle through the database of messages. If the time matches the current time the queue was ran then send the message. This means all the client has to do is update the time in the model. You don't have to worry about managing queues.

Comment: I suppose that is one option I had not considered.  I like it but need a little time to think through how that process effects the rest of my application.
Thanks for the suggestion.
I am still curious about how to reschedule a job in the queue once it is set using Queue::later( $someFutureTime)